# Using Javascript to modify user in about:config Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

In our site, we are using Windows authenticated to identify users (via intranet).  IE works perfectly.  However, we have to set the network.automatic-ntlm-auth value to our INTRANET website via about:config in Firefox.

My question would be:  Is it possible to change that value of "*network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris*" using Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't Firefox have enterprise distribution features?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, it will never be possible to change browser configuration from a webpage.